# Zoom UIView by using CGAffineTransformMakeScale and white background

Tags: uiview

I try to scale an UIView. And there is a white background outside of an UIview. How I can take it out to see just background view? Thanks!

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(.5,.5);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the background color of the view you need to be transparent to [UIColor clearColor]:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```